# Determine the number of towers of the form $\varnothing \subseteq A \subseteq B \subseteq \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Determine the number of towers of the form  $\varnothing \subseteq  A \subseteq B \subseteq \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$. It is an exercise problem in Richard's Introductory combinatorics.

My thought : There are $n$ Choose $k$ (length) subsets of $B$. Then, there are $2^k$ subsets $A$ of $B$. Thus, the total number of subsets is $\sum_k\binom{n}k\cdot 2^k$. Is this correct idea?

Note that: there is no meaning to the word "towers" other than what is given: subsets empty contained in $A$ contained in $B$ contained in $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Your idea is good but your phrasing is a bit imprecise.  There are "$n$ choose $k$" subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ **of size k**, and for each of those subsets of size $k$ there are $2^k$ subsets of that.  Summing over all possible cases and values of $k$ this brings the total to $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}2^k$.  Now, this can be simplified further if you so choose.  Hint: $2^k=2^k\cdot 1^{n-k}$

Comment: I see. It can be simplified to $3^n$ by the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2):

The towers of this form are in bijection with the $3^n$ maps $\{1,\ldots,n\}\to \{0,1,2\}$. Just let the map $f$ correspond with $A=f^{-1}(2)$ and $B=A\cup f^{-1}(1)$, or in the other direction let a tower correspond to the map 
$$ f(x)=\#\bigl\{\,S\in\{A,B\}\bigm| x\in S\,\bigr\}$$